# font awesome icons not showing when dynamically loaded from custom script

Tags: php, css, font-awesome

I wrote a custom script to include various files that I make frequent requests. Examples of such files are :

- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap.js
- jquery.js
- jqueryui.js
- font-awesome.css

My custom script is named remote.php. I am including my random css and js files into my pages like this :

```
<!-- bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="remote.php?type=bscss" type="text/css">
<!-- font awesome css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="remote.php?type=facss" type="text/css">
<!-- bootstrap js -->
<link href="remote.php?type=bsjs" type="application/javascript">
<!-- jquery js -->
<link href="remote.php?type=jqueryjs" type="application/javascript">
```

Now, all the files I am including have been downloaded from their respective websites, uploaded to my server and installed / configured (if needed) per the instructions provided by home sites.

My script works as I expected it to, with one catch..... the font awesome icons show us blocks instead of icons. Everything else works great....

I have made sure to set headers in my remote.php file based on the script I am calling.

- .css headers set as text/css
- .js headers set as application/javascript

The font awesome css files src attribute have been update to the full url of my website, but still nothing.

The icons work if I directly call the font-awesome.css file (which is on my server), and if I have to do that to make the icons work, I will. However, having one script to include all my needed files makes life simpler, as such I would really like to get this figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue, which turned out to be a CORS issue and instead of returning a 404, it was returning a 403.

The solution was to edit my .htaccess file, located in the root of my server. The following code fixed my issue.

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Webfont access
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff?|woff2?|font.css|css)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.org"  
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must download fonts too. Probably you have relative paths to font-awesome fonts.

Comment: The fonts come in the download package. Also, the icons work, when I directly call the font-awesome.css file, which is on my server.... Again, they work when I directly link to the .css file and don't work when called dynamically.

Comment: Can you give me link to it if you have it online?

Comment: If you check network resources, are you getting any 404 ? I'm pretty sure this have problem with paths. If you using remote.php just to load content of remote file and then printing it, it will search for files on your server not on remote you getting your css from.

Comment: the browsers dev console has no 404 errors listed. as previously stated, ALL files are on my server. I am not linking to files on other servers. my custom script retrieves the requested files, which are on my server. As for the font-awesome css file.... I have tried using absolute and relative paths to the font-awesome fonts. still the icons do NOT display when using my custom script to link to the css file, but do work when I directly link to the css file.